# Sending email from localhst LAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

This questions has a lot of answers in case of windows os. I have a simple php script to send an email from localhost using the XAMPP on Ububtu OS

```
   <?php
     mail('recipent@address', 'subect', 'body');
   ?>
```

To make mail function work I added the following lines to the php.ini file

```
 SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port=587
 sendmail_form=myaddress@gmail.com
 sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

The location of the sendmail is
/usr/sbin
However the phperror file has the following error

```
sh: 1: usrsbinsendmail: not found
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how to link the XAMPP to sendmail?

Comment: I think it's : sendmail_path="/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

Comment: what's wrong with the path?

Comment: it's not /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i but "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i" with the " at the begin and the end

Comment: I think this has answers over on ServerFault. Also in the PHP docs for php.ini.